# How do I declare SBT dependencies withSources that have test scope in published pom file?

Tags: scala, maven, testing, dependencies, sbt

When attempting to publish:
https://github.com/thetrav/http-stub-server-scala/blob/master/project/build.scala

The test framework dependencies are leaking into the runtime dependencies.
I've narrowed it down to the line:

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M5b" % "test" withSources(),
```

The problem appears to be withSources() which does not get published with the test scope

Is there a way for me to get the sources in test and dev, but not in the runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withSources` is not recommended in sbt 0.10+. The IDE plugins use `updateClassifiers`, for example, and this can be used by other tasks/plugins that do similar things.